# Operator overloading [] in templated Dynamic Array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the [] operator in a templated dynamic array, however it doesn't seem to be doing anything?

I created a templated dynamic array for school, I've tried separating the overload to outside the class.

The DynArray.h

```
template <typename T>
class DynArray
{
public:
    //The constructor initialises the size of 10 and m_Data to nullptr
    DynArray(void)
    {
        m_AllocatedSize = 10;
        m_Data = nullptr;
    }

    //deletes m_Data
    ~DynArray()
    {
        delete[] m_Data;
        m_Data = nullptr;
    }

    T* operator [] (int index)
    {
        return m_Data[index];
    }

    //creates the array and sets all values to 0
    T* CreateArray(void)
    {
        m_Data = new T[m_AllocatedSize];
        m_UsedElements = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_AllocatedSize; ++i)
        {
            m_Data[i] = NULL;
        }

        return m_Data;
    }

private:

    bool Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        if (a > b)
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    T* m_Data;
    T* m_newData;
    int m_AllocatedSize;
    int m_UsedElements;
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DynArray.h"
int main()
{
    DynArray<int>* myArray = new DynArray<int>;
    //runs the create function
    myArray->CreateArray();

    int test = myArray[2];

    delete myArray;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the overload to return in this case the int at m_Data[2], however it doesn't seem to overload the [] at all instead says `no suitable conversion from DynArray<int> to int`.

Comment: You are creating a pointer to a single `DynArray` then accessing the third one which doesn't exist. You can use `(*myArray)[2]` to access the pointer returned by `[]` but keep in mind, it's a pointer and probably not what you want.

Comment: `m_AllocatedSize = 10;` along with `m_Data = nullptr;` doesn't seem right. If the allocated size is ten, without allocating anything it looks like you're setting up for fail.

Comment: Oh wait there it is down in `CreateArray`. I recommend a read of [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii). It will help you write more robust code that is actually simpler.

Comment: Much appreciated, will definitely give it a read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer which is not what you want. You should do like this:

```
T& operator [] (const int& index)
 { 
    return   m_Data[index];
 }
```

Also `myArray` is a pointer you have to dereference it before using.

```
int test = (*myArray)[2];
```

It's better to not to use pointer:

```
    int main()// suggested by @user4581301
{
    DynArray<int> myArray;
    //runs the create function
    myArray.CreateArray();

    int test = myArray[2];


    return 0;
}
```

There is no reason for using pointers here.

Instead of `new` and `delete` for dynamic allocation it is better to use `smart pointer`s.
There is also one issue here, you are not chacking the range and what if theindex was for example a negative number.

Comment: Thanks, plan to add range checking, however changing the ```T*``` to ```T&``` still shows ```no suitable conversion function from DynArray<int> to int exists```

Comment: Its because your variable is a pointer and the compiler tries to interpret your variable as array. Try without heap allocation (new)

Comment: It's still a pointer. This is not a good place to use a dynamic allocation. Save new for times you really need it. [That's almost never.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new). Give `int main() { DynArray<int> myArray; myArray.CreateArray(); int test = myArray[2]; return 0; }` a try instead.

Comment: @user4581301 he already removed pointer. I add to the answer though.